# How to auto refresh individual tabs in a GWT tabpanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, tabs

I have a simple application where I have a Tabpanel with multiple tabs added to it. Each tab will fetch data from external URLs and displays data.

The data in those external URLs keeps changing at every 30 mins, but the URL address remains same.

So when I click on individual tabs without refreshing the whole page,  the refreshed data is not visible in the tabs after the original content in the URL changed. I'm using iframe to display the contents of the external URLs in each tab.

My question here, how to make each tab autorefresh (or) reload the tab upon clicking the tab header?

I have gone through few already posted stackoverflow questions, but didn't help completely.

Currently I'm using http meta tags to refresh the whole browser every 30 sec. But the problem with this is, the browser is setting to first tab, and the user again had to click on the tab of his choice, and this annoys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a selection handler to your tab panel. and check the selected tab item from the event. then set the url to relevant frame again.

**example**

```
// Create an empty tab panel
        TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();

        // create contents for tabs of tabpanel
        final Frame cotent1 = new Frame( "http://www.youtube.com/embed/j6cxZp4ii6c?autoplay=true" );
        final Frame cotent2 = new Frame( "http://www.youtube.com/embed/j6cxZp4ii6c?autoplay=true" );

        // create titles for tabs
        String tab1Title = "TAB 1";
        String tab2Title = "TAB 2";

        // create tabs
        tabPanel.add( cotent1, tab1Title );
        tabPanel.add( cotent2, tab2Title );

        // select first tab
        tabPanel.selectTab( 0 );

        // set width if tabpanel
        tabPanel.setWidth( "400" );

        tabPanel.addSelectionHandler( new SelectionHandler<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSelection( SelectionEvent<Integer> event )
            {
                           if(event.getSelectedItem() == 0)
                           {
                              cotent1.setUrl( "http://www.youtube.com/embed/j6cxZp4ii6c?autoplay=true" );
                            }
                           // likewise set the urls to all the content

            }
        } );
```

Comment: I have followed this before posting this question, but the silly mistake at my end was keeping tabPanel.selectTab( 0 ); after addSelectionHandler. Thanks for the help. It's working cool now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go with URL's. Just listen to the change on tabs and do the necessary

```
yourTabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {
  @Override
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
    if (event.getSelectedItem() == 1) {
      // do something here // get data for tab1
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess on this will be,

You must have a click handler for all the tabs and on click of the tab basically refresh the `DataProvider` you are using to populate data. This depends on what way you are using to display data. 
You need to refresh the data container that needs to be displayed. If you can post your code some one might help better with a more appropriate solution.

Further more you can call the `selectTab(int index,boolean fireEvents)` after an interval instead of refreshing the browser.